# How to add checkboxes and link to a model in Vuejs Treeview?

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, treeview, checkboxlist

I want to add checkboxes to [Vuejs Treeview](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/tree-view.html). So I added a checkbox to the template as this code:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="item-template">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
    <span
      :class="{bold: isFolder}"
      @click="toggle"
      @dblclick="changeType">
      {{ model.name }}
      <span v-if="isFolder">[{{ open ? '-' : '+' }}]</span>
    </span>
    <ul v-show="open" v-if="isFolder">
      <item
        class="item"
        v-for="(model, index) in model.children"
        :key="index"
        :model="model">
      </item>
    </ul>
  </li>
</script>
```

But I don't know how to link those checkboxes to a model like this [example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox). Please help! Thank you very much!

Comment: I intend to add a link to jsfidle but not yet successful: https://jsfiddle.net/059kefmh/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way to do that is by using [VueX](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).

The store has a common variable for all checkBoxes accessible from everywhere.

When you click on a checkbox, it update the store.

https://jsfiddle.net/u91mxc58/14/

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    checkBoxes:[],
  },
  mutations: {
    updateCheckBoxes(state, value) {
      state.checkBoxes = value;
    }
  }
})

// demo data
var data = {
  name: 'My Tree',
  children: [
    { name: 'hello' },
    { name: 'wat' },
    {
      name: 'child folder',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'child folder',
          children: [
            { name: 'hello' },
            { name: 'wat' }
          ]
        },
        { name: 'hello' },
        { name: 'wat' },
        {
          name: 'child folder',
          children: [
            { name: 'hello' },
            { name: 'wat' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

// define the item component
Vue.component('item', {
  template: '#item-template',
  props: {
    model: Object,
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      open: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isFolder: function () {
      return this.model.children &&
        this.model.children.length
    },
    checkBoxes: {
    // accesseur
    get: function () {
      return store.state.checkBoxes;
    },
    // mutateur
    set: function (newValue) {
      store.commit('updateCheckBoxes', newValue);
    }
  }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function () {
      if (this.isFolder) {
        this.open = !this.open
      }
    },
    changeType: function () {
      if (!this.isFolder) {
        Vue.set(this.model, 'children', [])
        this.addChild()
        this.open = true
      }
    },
    addChild: function () {
      this.model.children.push({
        name: 'new stuff'
      })
    }
  }
})

// boot up the demo
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: function() {
   return {
      treeData: data
    };
  },
  computed: {
    checkBoxes() {
       return store.state.checkBoxes;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Menlo, Consolas, monospace;
  color: #444;
}
.item {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul {
  padding-left: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  list-style-type: dot;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.0.1/vuex.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<!-- item template -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="item-template">
  <li>
   <input v-model="checkBoxes" type="checkbox" :value="model.name" id="checkbox">
    <span
      :class="{bold: isFolder}"
      @click="toggle"
      @dblclick="changeType">
      {{ model.name }}
      <span v-if="isFolder">[{{ open ? '-' : '+' }}]</span>
    </span>
    <ul v-show="open" v-if="isFolder">
      <item
        class="item"
        v-for="(model, index) in model.children"
        :key="index"
        :model="model">
      </item>
      <li class="add" @click="addChild">+</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</script>

<p>(You can double click on an item to turn it into a folder.)</p>

<!-- the demo root element -->
<ul id="demo">
<div>{{ checkBoxes }}</div>
  <item
    class="item"
    :model="treeData">
  </item>
</ul>
```